# make div appear when var is bigger than 14. otherwise keep it hidden

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>var div = document.getElementById('demo');

    if (totaal > 14) {
      div.style.display = 'block';
      div.style.visibility='visible';
    }

    else {
      div.style.display = 'none';
      div.style.visibility='hidden';
    }</script>
```

when using this script the div stays hidden and doesnt become bigger. Anyone know what i can do to make the div appear when var 'totaal' is bigger than 14?
Thanks

Edit1: var totaal is already set earlier in the script. Its a large script with adding and subtracting 1 from 'totaal'. That part isn't neccesary so I didn't include it.

Comment: Your code seems good. Where is the code that set "totaal" ?

Comment: You don't have `totaal` defined you will get ReferenceError. You need to assign actual value like `var totaal = parseInt(div.style.fontSize);`

Comment: Why would you expect `totaal` to ever be greater than 14?  Or have any value in it at all?

Comment: Are you sure that `totaal` is an **integer value**, and not e.g. an HTML Element? Common mistake is to do `var totaal = document.getElementById('totaal')` instead of something like `var totaal = parseInt(document.getElementById('totaal').value)`.

Comment: You need to wrap this code in a function,say `toggleDiv` and then call this `toggleDiv` function whenever you change the value of `totaal`

Comment: Agree with the other comments.  Additionally, the timing in which this code is executed might be another important consideration.  There is not enough details to be sure.

Comment: why are you setting both display and visibility? To really really make sure it is hidden?

Comment: So the unanswered question is "What is totaal and how is it set?" When you ask a question stick around to answer the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function to toggle your div based on the value of totaal :

```
function toggleDiv(totaal) {
  var div = document.getElementById('demo');

  if (totaal > 14) {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Now, all the time you change tootal, you can call this function with totaal as parameter to toggle the div

Comment: when adding the function to the code. the div always appears even when 'totaal' is smaller than 14. do you know what im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the code where you set the value of totaal ?